# Using popen in c++ and storing them in a dynamic size char array

Tags: c++, unix

I am trying to execute a shell command using popen in c++.

```
FILE *ls_cmd = popen("command","r");
                if (ls_cmd == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "popen(3) error");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                **static char buff[1064];**
                size_t n;

                while ((n = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff)-1, ls_cmd)) > 0) {
                    buff[n] = '\0';

                }
```

Since, i do not the results returned by the command priorly, if the result returned in very huge, i am not able to store all the results in the buff, because i have statically allocated a memory of 1024 to my char array.

How can i dynamically alloc, re-alloc my char buff[] array such that my buff[] does not miss out any of the values returned by my popen command which executed the shell command.?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you tagged your question `c++`, you should use c++ish style of memory management. So you can use `std::vector` to allocate, reallocate and free of memory fragments. Here is example

```
FILE *ls_cmd = popen("ls ~","r");
if (ls_cmd == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "popen(3) error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

std::vector<uint8_t> buff;
const std::size_t delta = 1024;
std::size_t cursor = 0;
buff.resize(delta);

std::size_t n;

while ((n = fread(buff.data()+cursor, 1, buff.size()-cursor, ls_cmd)) > 0) {
    cursor += n;
    if (cursor == buff.size()){
        if (buff.capacity() == buff.size()){
            buff.reserve(buff.size() + delta);
        }
        buff.resize(buff.capacity());
    }
}
buff[cursor] = '\0';
buff.resize(cursor+1);
```

Initially we have empty buffer `buff`, then we resize it to `delta` size and setting our `cursor` to the beginnig of buffer. After that, every time we read data block to pointer inside buffer at cursor, we move cursor to byte after last read and if it is end of buffer we increase buffer up to its size plus `delta`. In the end we write `\0` to cursor position and resize buffer to cursor+1 size to truncate possible extra space.

Now we can convert result either to c string aka `char *` or copy data to `std::string` if needed:

```
char *c_like_string = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff.data());
std::string cpp_string(buff.begin(), buff.end());
```

Comment: buff.resize() is giving me a memory fault, since it consumes stack space to construct each new object.

Comment: @Heggy, buff.resize() does not cunsumes stack, it allocates new chunk of memory in heap and copies data there. Show your code. My code runs perfect on my machine.

Comment: I was using a vector<string> buff which was giving me memory faults. I changed the same to use  vector<uint8_t> buff, and then type casted it to string. Works perfectly. Thanks mate !

Comment: @Heggy, I updated answer to show how to use resulted buffer as `char *` or `std::string` if needed.

Comment: Needs more `const`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, did you mean `delta`?

Comment: A wrinkle is that vector will increase the capacity exponentially, so having resized to size+delta, we could then resize *again* to capacity.  For large outputs, this will reduce the number of calls to fread.

Comment: @MartinBonner Oh, I see.

Comment: It was *good enough* before.  Personally, I would have written as: `if (cursor == buff.size()){
        buff.reserve(buff.size() + delta);  /* get more space */
        buff.resize(buff.capacity()); /* use any extra space vector allocated */
    }` ... but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

A short comment on the previous answer:
If you're going to do

```
std::string cpp_string(buff.begin(), buff.end());
```

then it's better to drop

```
buff[cursor] = '\0';
buff.resize(cursor+1);
```

and instead write

```
buff.resize(cursor);
```

To avoid an unnecessary `'\0'` in your `cpp_string`.